# Error while trying to install numpy through pip in Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, installation

I'm having an issue while trying to install numpy through the pipenv using python3.8 interpreter. I get a VERY large error dump in the console. I had success installing numpy with python3 interpreter so i'm not understanding why i can't with the most current python version. There error log is so long I had to upload it:

https://textuploader.com/108j9

--Thanks

Comment: As a general rule, you should read your error messages from the bottom up. The issue here is probably straightforward: `SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.`

Comment: I did notice that the error recommended to install python-dev but it was not explicit enough for a novice like me to notice that I had to install python(version)-dev. I had tried sudo apt-get install python-dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is:

```
  _configtest.c:1:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include <Python.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems that you are missing the header files for building Python 3.8 modules specifically. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```

Comment: My man....That was absolutely my issue. I appreciate the quick and concise answer!

Comment: Thank you! You are resolve numpy issue. 
For Python 3.9: 
sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.9:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.9-dev
```